# count data with composite key

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have these tables:

```
create table department (
  id int auto_increment,
  dep varchar(10),
  primary key (id));

create table employee (
  ssn varchar(10),
  name varchar(10),
  dep int,
  reg year,
  primary key (ssn,dep),
  foreign key(department) references department(id));
```

employees have different department experience and recorded in employee table. i have trouble with showing number of employee with last department for each department in my php script. it should be

```
no.|  department | number of employees
1  |  A          |       
2  |  B          |      
3  |  C          |      
4  |  D          |
```

i hope you understand, because i can't speak english well.. :)

Comment: What code have you tried?  We're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest date for each employee.  Then join back to the data to get the department, and do an aggregation:

```
select dept, count(*)
from employee e join
     (select ssn, max(reg) as maxy
      from employee
      group by ssn
     ) ee
     on e.ssn = ee.ssn and e.reg = ee.maxy
group by dept;
```

By the way, you have a poor data structure.  Your employee table should have one row per employee (with an obvious primary key).  You should then have another table, called something like `EmployeeDepartment` that has the department information.

Comment: Wouldn't you only want an EmployeeDepartment table if an employee can belong to multiple departments?  I would suspect that would depend on the organization's requirements.

Comment: @devon . . . That is how I interpret "employees have different department experience . . . ".

Comment: Ah, I interpreted it as they have a different amount of experience.  You may be right.